# What are these boxed doors outside store fronts in New York?

Tags: new-york-city, identify-this

In New York around lower Manhattan I saw some storefronts with these boxed doors outside.
What are they called and what is their function?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many other towns have these built right into the building.   In the suburban midwest you must always go through 2 doors to get into a Mcdonalds, Starbucks, Wendys, Trader Joes, etc.

Comment: The same in Sweden.  In some buildings, the inner door won't open before the outer door is closed (in particular with automatic sliding doors).

Comment: An interesting point is, I've never known what these are called!   People just call them "the double door thingy that you add on in winter".

Answer (score 80, accepted):

That is a [sidewalk vestibule](https://www.eater.com/2017/1/31/14445302/restaurant-vestibule-winter-warmer).  The idea is to have an extra door between the building's interior and the outside, so as to reduce the amount of air exchanged when people go in and out.  In winter, warm air stays inside and cold air stays outside, reducing the building's heating costs and avoiding uncomfortable drafts for diners sitting near the door.

You could also have a vestibule inside the restaurant's regular doors, but that would occupy valuable floor space, and would be useless during warmer seasons.  The temporary vestibule can be put up in winter and taken down in summer.

Comment: It has something to do with keeping flying insects outside as well.

Comment: In general, perhaps.  In New York City, not so much - as the article points out, they are used primarily in winter, when flying insects are not found outdoors.

Comment: For heating/air conditioning, as stated, is the usual purpose.  However, I have been in a couple of places where staff could lock the outer door remotely, and lock the inner while a thief is trying the outer.  Temporary jail till the police arrive!

Comment: I think you'd have considerable trouble getting away with one of those fire-hazards directly on the public pavement in the UK. Double doorways are always on the inside here & are part of the regular building - & subject to regular building regs.

Comment: @WGroleau In that case, it's called a *mantrap* and is usually built much more sturdily.

Comment: @Tetsujin NYC has plenty of bureaucracy, and I'm sure that there are fire rules for how these must be constructed (e.g., the external door still opens outward into the street, etc.).

Comment: As the article points out, it is surprising the NYC allows them at all just from the standpoint of sidewalk obstructions. Most cities don't allow businesses to just expand their entryway into the public sidewalk, and NYC does have plenty of bureaucracy. This just happens to be something they don't care about.

Comment: those have absolutely zero connection to "trap" doors (such as used in banks)

Comment: This answer is correct, though it's really not about a heating bill so much as it is about enabling comfortable seating just inside the door to the restaurant (which is correctly mentioned in the answer, I'm just changing the emphasis on the why). If you've ever eaten near the door in a restaurant *without* one of these, in new york in winter, then you'll completely understand why they exist. Every time someone opens the door you wince and brace yourself for the gust of freezing air. Tourists waiting in line will sometimes hold the door open without realizing the effect it has.

Comment: I'm sure the city does care about them.  I'd imagine you'd have to get a permit to have one.
https://www1.nyc.gov/nycbusiness/description/sidewalk-cafe-license

Comment: In addition to the purpose of keeping heat inside there's the related purpose of keeping cold outside--avoiding a blast of cold air in the shop when someone goes through the door.

Comment: @ZachLipton If you look at the images shown, they don't seem to be extending into public sidewalk, but rather into exterior floorplan of the store itself (and outdoor seating is less likely to be used in winter anyway!)

Answer (score 13):

While I do not know what they are called, their purpose is to keep heat inside by creating an extra air chamber between the inside which is heated and the outside. These are usually removed in the warmer months.